populate month-Year columns using given start date dynamically
I am trying to build a dynamically table with columns when we supply a start date
i.e.
Source Table like this:



Income#
recurrent income
no of recurrences
income start date




1
10000
5
2024/01/28



The output required:



Income#
income start date
2024-01
2024-02
2024-03
2024-04
2024-05




1
2024/01/28
10000
10000
10000
10000
10000



Please help if anyone has idea of how to build a SQL script. thanks
I tried CTE function, it did not work

That's a SQL Anti-Pattern; SQL is a statically and strongly typed language, which includes a query having a fixed (non varying) number of columns. The correct relational database result would be one Row per recurrence. So, why do you think you want a dynamically varying number of columns?

it is just a virtual view, not a static dataset. so, dynamically create  columns, CROSS JOIN?

So what happens if you have two Income# with different income start dates or a different no of recurrences?. Also the you question with the DBMS you are using (SQL Server etc.)

Datasets, queries, inline views, views, etc, etc, all have static signatures; the columns, their names, their datatypes, and the number of them, can not vary dynamically.  You can only pivot / unpivot to a fixed and predetermined number of columns. Additionally the language itself is designed for normalised data, not for what you're asking for. So I ask again; why do you think you need this?

I am trying to use the CROSS APPLY method at least I can get row by row.
